# Measuring socket to socket latency in Python

Tags: python, sockets, timestamp, latency

I'm using the Python socket library to send a message to another server and measure the roundtrip latency.  I'm new networks so it's very basic, just using the send-receive examples given in the socket docs (http://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication). For the moment I'm using time.time() to timestamp when the message goes out and when it comes back, though I want to be able to get nanosecond accuracy in the end.  Right now, I get about 300microseconds through my python script but pinging from the shell yields about 100micros. What can I do to get faster communication and/or more accurate measurement?

Script that sends one message:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                       socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
print "SENT {0}".format(int(time.time()*1000*1000)
```

This is the script that listens for the ping to come back

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "originating side localhost ip"
UDP_PORT = 9112
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                        socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    if data is not None:
        print "received message: {0} {1}".format(data, int(time.time()*1000*1000)
```

This is the script that listens on the server being pinged.  When it receives a message on the port, it sends a message right back

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "pinged server's localhost ip"
UDP_PORT = 9111

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

UDP_IP2 = "ip of server that sent ping"
UDP_PORT2 = 9112
MESSAGE = "HEY"
sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

print "Listening on PORT 9111" 

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    if data is not None:
        sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP2, UDP_PORT2))
        print "received message: ", data
```

Comment: Your scripts needed some tweaking, but I ran this on my linux system and got 150 microseconds. You display times in microseconds... are you sure that your time was 300 milliseconds? Also, time.time() is low-res on windows. Use time.time() on linux and time.clock() on windows.

Comment: Yea you're right, I meant micros, corrected my post.  It's only gonna be ran on linux so no problem there. I only get about 250-300 micros.